# 'Have a look at it' or 'take a look at it'?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

If I want somebody to see my work what should I use...

> Please **have** a look at it
>   Please **take** a look at it

If one of them is wrong then what's the reason for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of the sentences that you suggested are grammatically correct, natural and widely used. **take** is slightly more formal, and as such is probably used more often in writing. This is borne out by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20a%20look%20at%2C%20take%20a%20look%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20look%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20look%20at%3B%2Cc0).

If you need to say **please** in front of it, you are probably dealing with somebody that you don't know or is your work superior, and would be more likely to adopt a formal tone and use **take**.

> Please take a look at it

With a friend, relative or co-worker, you would probably replace **please** with **can** or **could**, or omit it completely, or move it to the end of the sentence, and use **have**.

> Can you have a look at it, please?
>   Could you have a look at it?
>   Have a look at it, please.

Comment: In the first sentence, you have said to use take still you are using have why?

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari I did not say "use take". I said "take is slightly more formal". I then provide one example for a formal setting using take, and three examples for an informal setting using have.

Answer (score 2):

My impression is that "have a look at it" implies more of at looking up something in a book, while "take a look at it" means, or at least feels, like more of looking at something out through a window.